# JSON alimentado por while

Tags: php, javascript

Tenho um contrutor de Gráficos que é alimentado por JSON o que eu queria erra gerar casas dinamicamente ou seja ter um numero de elementos estipulado por uma variável.

Exemplo do que eu tentei fazer:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
// Get the context of the canvas element we want to select
var ctx = document.getElementById("piechart").getContext("2d");
var data = [
while(i=2)
{
{
    value: <?print $valor;?>,
    color:"#F7464A",
    highlight: "#FF5A5E",
    label: "Red"
},
i++;
}


];

var options = {
  animateScale: true
};

var myNewChart = new Chart(ctx).Pie(data,options);
```

Comment: Queres ter esse `while` no JavaScript ou no PHP?

Answer (score 1):

Nesse código o while esta dentro da váriavel data, a váriavel deve ser setada antes como um array e dentro do while você ir adicionando os valores.

Um exemplo próximo ao seu que deve funcionar:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
// Get the context of the canvas element we want to select
var ctx = document.getElementById("piechart").getContext("2d");
var data = [];
var i = 0;
while(i <= 2)
{
    data.push({
        value: <?print $valor;?>,
        color:"#F7464A",
        highlight: "#FF5A5E",
        label: "Red"
    });
    i++;
}

var options = {
  animateScale: true
};

var myNewChart = new Chart(ctx).Pie(data,options);
</script>
```

Comment: O corpo `while` vai ser executado alguma vez? Na linha anterior você define `i = 0` e na condição do `while` o `i` tem que ser igual a 2 para ser executado.

Comment: Bem observado @Otavio, corrigido a resposta :)

Answer (score 0):

Funcionou.Porem não estou conseguindo passar valor de um array do PHP.

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
```

// Get the context of the canvas element we want to select
var ctx = document.getElementById("piechart").getContext("2d");
var data = [];
var i = 0;
while(i <= )
{
    data.push({
        value: ,
        color:"#F7464A",
        highlight: "#FF5A5E",
        label: 
    });
    i++;
}

var options = {
  animateScale: true
};

var myNewChart = new Chart(ctx).Pie(data,options);

Comment: deve ter tido um problema na hora de colocar o código, seria possível atualizar sua pergunta com o código que você esta usando no momento?